# How can I disable ***all*** VC/git awareness?

Tags: git, version-control

Even when I start Emacs without any initialization file, it is still aware of version control.  (For example, if I visit a `git`-controlled file, the modeline will say something like "Git:some-branch".)

Is there a convenient way to disable ***all*** VC/git awareness?

The goal is to make Emacs' behavior entirely independent of whether a file is under version control or not.

Comment: Not that I know of: I believe you'd have to dump a new emacs with (some of) the vc/ stuff elided. The `autoloads` target of the Makefile in `emacs/lisp` is the relevant target. But the `vc/` subdir includes not only vc stuff, but also diff/ediff, emerge, add-log and various other things that you probably want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vc` is the package that handles version control for Emacs.  You can disable it by customizing `vc-handled-backends` to nil:

```
vc-handled-backends is a variable defined in `vc-hooks.el'.

Its value is (Git)
Original value was 
(RCS CVS SVN SCCS SRC Bzr Git Hg Mtn)

List of version control backends for which VC will be used.
Entries in this list will be tried in order to determine whether a
file is under that sort of version control.
Removing an entry from the list prevents VC from being activated
when visiting a file managed by that backend.
An empty list disables VC altogether.
```

Comment: Just a word of caution: IIUC, doing this will make it hard for something like `project.el` to work with Git-projects.